# Android set unicode String to textview

Tags: android, unicode

i can simply set Unicode chars/string to TextView by `text` properties on `xml` layout as:

```
android:text="&#xf0f3;"
```

but i can't set Unicode from java code like with this:

```
icon_notify_post_message.setText("&#xf0f3;");
```

`"&#xf0f3;"` is icon which i found from this [site](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/), its only work when i try to set it from xml layout, not working when i try to set is from java code

Comment: set your text string.xml file and access text

Comment: You need to set the font to the TextView first.

Comment: @RameshPrajapati Thanks, problem resolved

Answer (score 1):

Save the unicode in **String.xml** with some name. Then for setting it in `textView` use this:

```
icon_notify_post_message.setText(getstring(//your string)).
```

It's recommended and standard way of using unicode in `textView`.
 or a very common way of doing this (the way I use):

```
String str = "\u00C7" + getContext().getString(R.string.your_string);

Entering the text as HTML in java:

yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your chars"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code (replace `&#xFOO32;` with your unique code):

```kotlin
val uniqueCode = "&#xFOO32;"

val spannedText: Spanned = Html.fromHtml(uniqueCode,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

yourText.text = spannedText
```